# jquery resizing div problems using operators

Tags: jquery

i hope anyone can help me with this,

i have 3 squares and i want to use animate on the squares but with an operator such as ">" or ">"

but i have no idea how i can implement this,

the on click function works but if u click the second div when the first div is doing an animate, turns out that both divs will be expanded,
the purpose is that when the first div is expanded the other one is not, and so on,
try and see

```
    $(function () {
       $("#square1").on("click", function () {
        if ($("#square2").css('width') == '500px') {
            $("#square2").animate({
                width: "50"
            }, 1000);
            $("#square1").animate({
                width: "500"
            }, 1000);
        } else if ($("#square1").css('width') == '500px') {
            $("#square1").animate({
                width: "50"
            }, 1000);
        } else {
            $("#square1").animate({
                width: "500"
            }, 1000);
                }
            });
        });
$(function () {
    $("#square2").on("click", function () {
        if ($("#square1").css('width') == '500px') {
            $("#square1").animate({
                width: "50"
            }, 1000);
            $("#square2").animate({
                width: "500"
            }, 1000);
        } else if ($("#square2").css('width') == '500px') {
            $("#square2").animate({
                width: "50"
            }, 1000);
        } else {
            $("#square2").animate({
                width: "500"
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
});
$(function () {
    $("#vierkant").on("click", function () {
        if ($("#square1").css('width') == '500px') {
            $("#square1").animate({
                width: "50"
            }, 1000);
            $("#square2").animate({
                width: "50"
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c34Ha/

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean incrementing them by a certain amount, += - I'm not sure how you'd animate with the greater than symbol...?

Comment: check out jquery deferred...http://jsfiddle.net/catfood/VXpp3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if any of the div's is being animated before animating the other one by adding

```
if (!$("#square1").is(':animated')) {
    // do stuff
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c34Ha/1/